# Fix all node modules' version numbers to the currently using ones in package.json

Tags: node.js, package.json

Currently, all node modules in package.json are using `*` as the version number, my application is quite stable with those node modules, so I want to fix their version numbers in package.json, so that I can run `npm install` in other places to install node modules with expected versions.

Is there a way to do it quickly instead of changing them one by one manually?

Such as some console commands, `npm fixversion module_a module_b ...`?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for

```
npm shrinkwrap
```

See [the documentation here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) for more information.

It will generate an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` with the current versions, and it takes precedence over package.json, so you can delete that file and `npm update` if you wish.

*UPDATE*

Here is a little script that writes out the `package.json` with the versions from the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` to a new file, `package-lockdown.json`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var p = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync( 'package.json') );
var v = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync( 'npm-shrinkwrap.json') );

updateDependencies( p.dependencies,    v.dependencies );
updateDependencies( p.devDependencies, v.dependencies );

fs.writeFileSync( 'package-lockdown.json', JSON.stringify( p, null, 2 ) );

function updateDependencies( list, v )
{
        for ( var d in list )
                list[d] = v[d].version;
}
```

The above script updates `devDependencies` aswell, so be sure to either remove that line or run `npm shrinkwrap --dev` before running the script.

Comment: Thank you, it is similar to what I want, but it is also giving me the packages that depended by modules I use. e.g. I am using `module_a` that depends on `module_b`, the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` would contain both `module_a` and `module_b`, in case I only want `module_a`.

Comment: I added a little script to do what you want, but it is non-standard, hence the need for a custom script. It is expected that npm-shrinkwrap.json contains transitive dependency versions, because if `module_a` specifies a version range for `module_b`, and `module_b` gets a new release, then someone running `npm install` won't get the exact same packages.