# Why does `npm install` use the shrinkwrap's 'resolved' property

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-shrinkwrap, npm-lazy

I am considering setting up a local npm mirror such as "npm_lazy" on my computer.
But it seems like `npm install` and `npm shrinkwrap` don't work well with local mirrors.

Let me explain. When there is an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file, the `npm install` command always requests packages from the URL specified in the shrinkwrap file's `"resolved"` property. So, even if I have a local npm mirror running at `http://localhost:12345/`, and even if I configure npm to use that as its registry, it will **not** request any package modules from my local mirror (unless a `"resolved"` property in the shrinkwrap file happens to point to `http://localhost:12345/`).

Basically, `npm install` ignores npm's registry configuration and follows the shrinkwrap `"resolved"` property.

Is there a reason why `npm install` uses the `"resolved"` property instead of constructing it dynamically with the dependency package name and version? Why does npm-shrinkwrap.json have this field at all?

So back to my issue. I want to use npm_lazy as a local npm mirror. I could rewrite all the `"resolved"` URLS in `npm-shrinkwrap.json` to point to `http://localhost:12345/`. But then my shrinkwrap file is less portable — my coworkers would not be able to use unless their computers have the same npm_lazy server running.

I have considered redirecting all `registry.npmjs.org` traffic to `localhost` in order to create a transparent mirror. But it would be too hard -- it needs to supoprt HTTPS, and also, how would npm_lazy access the true domain? I would have to specify it by its IP address, which may change.

Has anyone else attempted to do the same thing -- to set up a local-computer NPM cache? 
But, my main question is, why does npm use the "resolved" property? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Shrinkwrap locks down the dependencies, attempting to guarantee the same 'build' (or dependencies) for everyone using that shrinkwrap file. It not only locks down the versions, but also the repository URL, for the same reason: changing any of these potentially changes the content of the package, thus losing any guarantee. Of course, if shrinkwrap were aware of the concept of a repository cache or proxy, it should certainly use yours, but apparently it isn't.

Normally you'd replace the repository URL in `package.json` (since this is a source file) and run npm shrinkwrap again to re-generate the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file (since it is a generated file), and keep that on a local dev branch. But it is a hassle to keep configuration files separated.

So you could enter `cache.repository.example.com` as the repository hostname, and add a `CNAME` to DNS pointing to npmregistry. Anyone having npm_lazy installed locally could then safely override this DNS entry in their Hosts file to point to localhost.

However, there is a simpler solution to localize your checkout. Recently I answered a question with this [little script to update `package.json` versions with values from `npm-shrinkwrap.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323296/fix-all-node-modules-version-numbers-to-the-currently-using-ones-in-package-jso/33323380#33323380), which can easily be adapted to update all `resolved` properties in `npm-package.json` to use your proxy, and which I will leave as an excercise ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to avoid any change to `npm-shrinkwrap.json`'s `resolved` urls, since that would make other people's `npm install`s fail (since it would try to download the packages from that URL which is only valid for my computer). But yes, if my intranet had a local NPM registry, I could do that.

Comment: You wouldn't commit and push that file, of course - they are local modifications.

Comment: I've also found an easy way to get custom URLs in a shrinkwrap file. When `npm install` runs with a custom configured registry URL (either by `.npmrc` or using the `--registry` command option), it puts that URL in each `package.json` in `node_modules`, in a property called `_resolved`. Then, when `npm shrinkwrap` runs, those `_resolved` properties then get conveyed to the resulting `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file as `resolved` properties.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. It would require you to delete the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` though, and the versions may change. You would have the same problem though: the shrinkwrap file has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to save `resolved` property into `npm-package.json`.

The utility [shonkwrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shonkwrap) do the trick. But it impacts everybody in the team: type `shonkwrap` instead of `npm shrinkwrap`. Or you can write similar code into your build script (e.g. gulpfile) to delete `resolved` property from existing `npm-package.json`.